# What does a part after a colon in a Spring expression indicate?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I understand the part of `${user.configuredName}`, but I can't understand or find on google the part that is after that `:ABC`. Can anyone please explain what it does?

What I understand is this that `${user.configuredName}` will read the property from the properties using `messageSource`.

```
 <constructor-arg value="${user.configuredName:ABC}"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part after the : specifies a default value.
If user.configuredName is not defined, "ABC" will be used as default value.

-- edit added reference to match request made in comment :)
See here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4785

I was trying to find some more documentation about it, but it's a bit spread out in different pieces... I'll let you google the rest.

Comment: ok, this thing I guessed, but can you please provide some reference i.e. in documentation. I would like to read further. btw thanks for answer :) :)